How to nginx match exact / and /(any site)
I'm trying to set my application to redirect from root / to a default path. What I'm trying to do is when someone goes to https://apps.domain.com it will redirect to https://apps.domain.com/account which calls/redirects to the location / directive plus the path (account in this case). But if someone enters https://apps.domain.com/profile then it should just proxy_pass directly.

        location = / {
                return 301 $request_uri/auth;
        }

        location /i/ {
                proxy_pass https://oraclecloudapps.com/i/;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /  {
                proxy_pass https://oraclecloudapps.com/ords/r/apps/;
                proxy_set_header Origin "";
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_connect_timeout 600;
                proxy_send_timeout 600;
                proxy_read_timeout 600;
                send_timeout 600;
        }

Unfortunately I'm getting too many redirects here and not sure how to solve it. Appreciate any help.
